# How to change the message Error when registering a community user

Tags: customer-community, lightning-community, login

we're using community login by default from the package.

When we register a new user using an email and a user with that email already exists, We get this error:

"The request cannot be processed at this time. The administrator of the website has been notified."
I want to change the error message.

anyone can help me?

Thank you

Comment: Do you need this message altered during the sign up or login?

Comment: Hello, during the sign up

Comment: Look for 'Self Registration Page' in Site detail page. On further investigation of this page, you can locate the error string in related class and update your message.

Answer (score 0):

Look for 'Self Registration Page' in Site detail page. On further investigation of this page, you can locate the error string in related class and update your message